# Classify unclassified patches that were left after cloud removal for Landsat 8, using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, cloud-cover

I am trying to classify my study area, using Random Forest using Landsat 8 dataset of GEE. The first problem that I came across was clouds, so to remove them I used as follows

```
var mask = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks')

print(mask.help['landsatSR'])

var mask_function = mask.landsatSR() // mask function

var col_free = sr14.map(mask_function) // apply function to collection
var composite_free = col_free.max() // create composite using max

Map.addLayer(composite_free.clip(thane), vis, 'composite collection without clouds');
```

This removed clouds, but left large empty gaps in my study area. How can I fill these empty regions. My aim is to classify them further, but because of the empty gaps, results are getting hampered.

Here is my full [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/860bc89676c3b10bc820d680f32d41c0).

Update:
I tried Linear Interpolation method shown in [Spatial Thoughts](https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/11/08/temporal-interpolation-gee/#more-6094) but this showed very little difference, but the gaps remain.

```
var filtered = col_free.map(function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp')
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
})

//Interpolation-method
var days = 180

// Convert days to milliseconds
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var lessEqFilter = ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var greaterEqFilter = ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})

var filter1 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, lessEqFilter)
var join1 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'after',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: false})
  
var join1Result = join1.apply({
  primary: filtered,
  secondary: filtered,
  condition: filter1
})
print(join1Result.first())

var filter2 = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, greaterEqFilter)

var join2 = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'before',
  ordering: 'system:time_start',
  ascending: true})
  
var join2Result = join2.apply({
  primary: join1Result,
  secondary: join1Result,
  condition: filter2
})

print(join2Result.first())


// Do the interpolation

var interpolateImages = function(image) {
  var image = ee.Image(image)
  var beforeImages = ee.List(image.get('before'))
  var beforeMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(beforeImages).mosaic()
  var afterImages = ee.List(image.get('after'))
  var afterMosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(afterImages).mosaic()

  var t1 = beforeMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t1')
  var t2 = afterMosaic.select('timestamp').rename('t2')

  var t = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('t')

  var timeImage = ee.Image.cat([t1, t2, t])

  var timeRatio = timeImage.expression('(t - t1) / (t2 - t1)', {
    't': timeImage.select('t'),
    't1': timeImage.select('t1'),
    't2': timeImage.select('t2'),
  })
  
  var interpolated = beforeMosaic
    .add((afterMosaic.subtract(beforeMosaic).multiply(timeRatio)))
  
  var result = image.unmask(interpolated)
  return result.copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
}

var interpolatedCol = ee.ImageCollection(join2Result.map(interpolateImages))
```

Here is the [updated code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5ecdf6a8cc8b9338added9b0817e9a08).

Comment: Does your composite have to be from one specific time or would you be open to a time range? For example a composite ranging from Jan. 2021- Jan. 2022?

Comment: I need for months of March and Nov , starting from year 2015

Comment: And you just want a .tif result for further classificaiton?

Comment: yes, I want to create a LULC of it

Comment: Let me know if that is what you are after.